# How to use variable in a interpolated string for the 'endpoint' of 'aws_sns_topic_subscription'?

Tags: terraform

I want to use a variable for lambda function name. For example:

```
variable "lambda_function_name" {
  default = "my-project-lambda-func"
}


resource "aws_lambda_function" "${var.lambda_function_name}" {
  filename         = "${data.archive_file.package-zip.output_path}"
  function_name    = "this_is_a_test"
  handler          = "lambda_function.simple_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.package-zip.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "python3.7"
  tags             = "${var.tags}"
  timeout          = 300
}
```

I want to use the variable to create a SNS subscription:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "call_lambda_by_sns" {
  topic_arn = "${module.myproject_event_sns.arn}"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.${var.lambda_rotate_db_function_name}.arn}"
}
```

It throws this error when I run terraform validate

> Error reading config for
>   aws_sns_topic_subscription[call_lambda_by_sns]: parse error at 1:23:
>   expected "}" but found invalid sequence "$"

So I tried an alternative:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "call_lambda_by_sns" {
  topic_arn = "${module.myproject_event_sns.arn}"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "aws_lambda_function.${var.lambda_rotate_db_function_name}.arn"
}
```

Now the endpoint line causes this error:

```
Error: Error parsing address 'aws_lambda_function.${var.lambda_rotate_db_function_name}': invalid resource address "aws_lambda_function.${var.lambda_rotate_db_function_name}"
```

So what is the syntax to allow me to use a variable here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be completed after fixing a few issues

- You cannot use an interpolation in a resource name so change

  ```hcl
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "${var.lambda_function_name}" {
  ```

  to a hard coded, generic value

  ```hcl
  resource "aws_lambda_function" "default" {
  ```
- cannot use interpolation within an interpolation so change

  ```hcl
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.${var.lambda_rotate_db_function_name}.arn}"
  ```

  to use the generic name of `default` from above

  ```hcl
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.default.arn}"
  ```

Working Terraform

```hcl
variable "lambda_function_name" {
  default = "my-project-lambda-func"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "default" {
  filename         = "${data.archive_file.package-zip.output_path}"
  function_name    = "this_is_a_test"
  handler          = "lambda_function.simple_handler"
  source_code_hash = "${data.archive_file.package-zip.output_base64sha256}"
  runtime          = "python3.7"
  tags             = "${var.tags}"
  timeout          = 300
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_subscription" "call_lambda_by_sns" {
  topic_arn = "${module.myproject_event_sns.arn}"
  protocol  = "lambda"
  endpoint  = "${aws_lambda_function.default.arn}"
}
```